# Load php function after JS function call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my website I have to read, edit and save some datas. I perform it in this way:

1. Load with PHP a text file called `database.txt` (stored in the server) in a textarea that has `id="testo"`
2. Call `importa();` that is a javascript function that edit the text inside `testo`
3. I save content of the textarea inside `database.txt`

This is the code I use to load the text inside the textarea:

```
 <?php
$myFile = "database.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo '<textarea id="testo" style="width:100%;display:block;">'.$theData.'</textarea>';
?>
```

I have a button `Save` that calls `importa();`.

```
<input type="button" id="salvauser" value="Save" style="width:100%" onclick="document.getElementById('settings').style.display='none';importa();" />
```

Now I have the textarea that is edited from importa and I must save its text to `database.txt`. I wrote this function:

```
<?php
$testo = $_POST['testo']."\r\n";
$documento ="database.txt";
$identificatore = fopen($documento, "a");
if (!fwrite($identificatore, $testo)){
echo"?PHP ERROR: Cannot save the file. Script not loaded.";
exit;
}
else {
fclose($identificatore);
header('Location: http://escaperope.altervista.org/testsito/index.php');
}
?>
```

It saves the content of the textarea, but I don't know how to call this PHP script after calling `importa();` (I am new with PHP). Do you have any suggestions?

Here you can see `importa();`

```
function addText(elId,text) {
    document.getElementById(elId).value += text;
}

//addText allows me to add the text inside the textarea

function importa() {
 addText("testo",document.getElementById("nome2").value + ":" + document.getElementById("fc2").value+":" + document.getElementById("poke1").value + ":" + document.getElementById("poke2").value + ":" + document.getElementById("poke3").value + "tipo");
}
```

Comment: Remember that PHP is server side while javascript is client side, so you probably need to use ajax for this, please post the `importa()` function as well.

Comment: Done, I've added the function importa();

Comment: function savetext() {  jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST",url: "action.php", }); <--- could this work?

Comment: Try and see for yourself! But I'd say it is missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html5 way... Pure Javascript...

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
</style>
<script src="rw.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="testo"></textarea>
<button id="salva">Salva</button>
</body>
</html>
```

rw.js

```
function x(a,b,e,d,c){ // Url,callback,method,formdata or {key:val},placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 c.open(e||'get',a);
 c.onload=b;
 c.onerror=error;
 c.send(d||null)
}
function salva(){
 var fd=new FormData();
 fd.append('data',document.getElementById('testo').value);
 x('save.php',controllo,'post',fd);
}
function controllo(){
 if(this.response=='ok'){
  alert(this.response);//ok
  leggi();
 }else{
  alert(this.response);//errore
 }
}
function leggi(){
 x('database.txt',visualizza);
}
function visualizza(){
 document.getElementById('testo').value=this.response;
}
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById('salva').addEventListener('click',salva,false);
 leggi();
}
```

ajax source https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309057/2450730

after that you can execute addtext or whatever you want.

save.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['data']){
 $fh=fopen('database.txt','w') or die("non riesco ad aprire il file");
 echo (fwrite($fh,$_POST['data']))?'ok':'errore';
 fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

not tested ... but should work in modern browsers...

if you want to have more control over your database.. use JSON.parse() & JSON.stringify();

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

if you have any other questions just ask.

**EDIT**

i noticed now you want to store your users and pokes or whatever in the db.txt...

structure everything in a json way.. :

```
[
 {
  "nome":"pippo",
  "pokes":[
   {"time":05505151,"poketxt":"lol","type":"msg"},
   {"time":05505152,"poketxt":"lol2","type":"boh"}
  ]
 },
 {
  "nome":"ciccio",
  "pokes":[
   {"time":05505155,"poketxt":"lolx","type":"msg"},
   {"time":05505156,"poketxt":"lolxx","type":"boh2"}
  ]
 },
]
```

this is easely done with creating a javascript array...

then convert it to a text string to store into `database.txt`

using  `fd.append('data',JSON.stringify(javascriptArray))` inside the `salva` function

to read the text

inside the `visualizza` function

use `JSON.parse(this.response)` to transform your text back to a javascript array which contains all the data you need to create a nice display function.