# PHP/Javascript: better way to re-run PHP function after JS function

Tags: javascript, php, dry

when the page loads, it fires a PHP function, from the `functions.php` file, to grab data from the DB and populate a DOM element, like so:

`<h1>TOTALS: <?php fetchTotals(); ?></h1>`

after submitting data, via JS-handled form, i want to fire that PHP function *again* to update the totals and **not** repeat code.

i have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846441/load-php-function-after-js-function-call) to see if there was anything useful there.  and i already know i can just use `$.ajax` or `$.post` to run a file, but since the function already exists, and **i hate repeating code**, i wanted to know if there's a more *elegant* solution that obviates creating a file that exactly duplicates an already-extant function. follow me here?  DRY, good; duplicate, bad.

Again: looking for more **elegant** way, not a basic how-to.

if not, then that's just the beast and screw DRY.  but i want to be better.  :)

Comment: So just include your existing function from whichever PHP script is handling the form, and run it from there. You don't need two copies of it.

Comment: What code have you actually repeated?  If your page includes `functions.php` and calls a function, why can't another page include `functions.php` and call a function?  It sounds like you're trying to squeeze every possible keystroke you can out of your code, why?

Comment: Those answers aren't telling you to duplicate your code. If you have code that needs executing from several different sources than it should be extracted from where you currently have it and put in a central file.

Comment: @iainn code sample to illustrate?  not sure what you're trying to say here.

Comment: @David  the `fetchTotals()` function would need to be repeated.

Comment: @PatrickEvans  i didn't want to have to make several AJAX calls just to do a simple PHP function call.  seems, well,  i dunno... stop making sense!  :D

Comment: @WhiteRau: I don't see how simply calling a function more than once is "repeating code".  The whole purpose of encapsulating code within a function is to be able to easily invoke it in multiple places.  I guess if you really want the function to only ever be called from one place then you could remove it from the initial page load and just make AJAX calls for both the initial and the updated value.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a dispatcher file -- essentially just a php file that grabs a param you pass to it (dispatcher.php?action=fetchTotals for example) that acts upon the action and calls that named PHP method.  It could be just a simple php switch statement even.

Yes, it's an additional file.  That being said, you're not re-writing or duplicating any methods.  And, from a maintainability standpoint, if you have all your ajax calls going to a centralized dispatcher, it eases both readability and reuse.  As an extra bonus, you could code it such that a call to a particular named method could actually call multiple PHP methods.

Comment: If you go this route, you should whitelist the functions or put all the functions you want to call into a specific scope so you don't allow any old functions to be called (i.e. dispatcher.php?action=enableAdminMode)

Comment: okay.  so instead of a dedicated file for each AJAX call, just call the functions page and push the 'action=doThisFunction' to it... dang.  how did i not know about this?  :D  thank you!  @KodosJohnson, thanks for the whitelist reminder too.

Comment: i guess the thing that irritated me was that the function was right there to be called...it just had to be triggered.  and now all this friggin' hoopla just to do exactly that.  blech.